# Discord JS problem get username & avatarURL by mention

Tags: javascript, discord

i try to mention a member on my server discord and with this it's create a webhook with his username and avatarURL but it's not working, it's tell me my usermentioned don't have displayName

My code:

```
 if (cmd === "say")
    {
        message.delete()   
        let usermentioned = message.mentions.members.first();
        let msg = args.slice(1).join(" ");
      
        message.channel.createWebhook(usermentioned.displayName, 
        usermentioned.user.displayAvatarURL).then(wb =>        
          {       
            var Hook = new hookcord.Hook()
            .setLink(`https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/${wb.id}/${wb.token}`)
            .setPayload({ 
              'title': usermentioned.displayName,
              'avatar': usermentioned.user.displayAvatarURL,
              'content': msg
          })
          .fire()
          .then(function(response)
           {
            wb.delete();
        }) 
          .catch(function(e) {})
      })
    }
```

The error:

message.channel.createWebhook(usermentioned.displayName, usermentioned.user.displayAvatarURL).then(wb =>
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

at first you shoud try to run with debugger and track your variable  *usermentioned*. Or make output this variable to console. It give to you information about structure of user's profile. May be you get wrong level of profile